# How to check JSON String based on another JSON String?

Tags: php, json, loops

I'd like to do a loop with these JSON strings.

```
$json_m = '[
             {"name":"1","value":"1"},
             {"name":"2","value":"2"},
             {"name":"3","value":"3"},
             {"name":"4","value":"4"},
             {"name":"5","value":"5"},
           ]';

$json_a = '[
             {"name":"1-m","value":"1"},                 
             {"name":"2-m","value":"3"},                 
             {"name":"3-m","value":"5"},
           ]';
```

I do a loop and on `$json_m`. If the value exists in both JSON, I set the parameter to `TRUE`

This is my current code:

```
$jm         = json_decode($json_m, true);
$ja         = json_decode($json_a, true);

$i          = 0;
$is_exist   = FALSE;
    
    foreach($jm as $rows ){
        
        if($rows["value"] == $ja[$i]["value"]){
            $is_exist   = TRUE;
        }
            
        $dataadd    = array (   'ID'        => $i,
                                'NAME'      => $rows["value"],
                                'STATUS'    => $is_exist
                            );
        $i++;
        
    }
```

This script returns as all FALSE, based on my example the `STATUS` should return like this:

```
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

Do I miss something or what? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have for every element on m-array you need to do a loop through a-array, also you need to do $is_exist   = FALSE; in the first line in the forloop

Comment: so, I need to loop a-array inside m-array? I try do that. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using array_search like below

```
$json_m = '[
             {"name":"1","value":"1"},
             {"name":"2","value":"2"},
             {"name":"3","value":"3"},
             {"name":"4","value":"4"},
             {"name":"5","value":"5"}
           ]';

$json_a = '[
             {"name":"1-m","value":"1"},                 
             {"name":"2-m","value":"3"},                 
             {"name":"2-m","value":"3"},  
             {"name":"3-m","value":"5"}
           ]';

$jm         = json_decode($json_m, true);
$ja         = json_decode($json_a, true);

$javal = array_unique(array_column($ja, 'value'));


$is_exist   = FALSE;
$dataadd =[];
foreach($jm as $i=> $rows ){
        $is_exist   = FALSE;
        if(is_numeric(array_search($rows["value"], $javal))) {
            $is_exist   = TRUE; 
        }
        $dataadd[]    = array (   'ID'        => $i,
                                'NAME'      => $rows["value"],
                                'STATUS'    => $is_exist
                            );
    }
    print_r($dataadd);
```

Comment: demo link https://onlinephp.io/c/a3894

Answer (score 1):

You could make your life easier by extracting all the `value` values from `$ja` using `array_column`; you can then search that using `in_array`. You can then iterate `$jm` using `array_map` to produce an array of `$dataadd` values:

```php
$ja_values = array_column($ja, 'value');

$dataadd = array_map(fn ($arr, $idx) => array('ID' => $idx, 'NAME' => $arr['value'], 'STATUS' => in_array($arr['value'], $ja_values)), $jm, array_keys($jm));

var_export($dataadd);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 0,
    'NAME' => '1',
    'STATUS' => true,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 1,
    'NAME' => '2',
    'STATUS' => false,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 2,
    'NAME' => '3',
    'STATUS' => true,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 3,
    'NAME' => '4',
    'STATUS' => false,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 4,
    'NAME' => '5',
    'STATUS' => true,
  ),
)
```